# JQuery autocomplete on generated input with "recycled" id

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a table consisting of rows with inputs. Rows are cloned and added dynamically whenever an autocomplete value is selected in the first input of each row.

Each time a new row is added, I want to apply .autocomplete to the first input. Normally this is easy, as seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Za3Vu/27/).

I have a somewhat different approach, where I'm changing the ID of the input where a selection is made. I think that's why I'm unable to apply autocomplete to the cloned line, but I can't figure out why??

Here's the code in question ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8utjg/3/))

```
// Make new line. (I have additional code for improved functionality in my production code)
function newLine() {
    // Send the line to backend for updating mysql. Data returned is
    // the mysql id for the "autocompleted" line. Emulated here by a random number
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
    $("#idLine0").attr("id", "idLine" + randomNumber)

    //Make clone of the last line
    var row = $("#test tr:last").clone(true);

    //Give the ID "idLine0" (which I've reserved for the bottom line) to the new line.
    $(".AC", row).val("").attr({
        "id": "idLine0",
        "placeholder": "Autocomplete does not work here"
    })

    row.insertAfter("#test tr:last");
    //$(".AC").autocomplete("destroy")
    applyAutocomplete("#idLine0")
}

function applyAutocomplete(id) {
  $(id).autocomplete({
    source: [{
        value: "ActionScript",
        type: "type 1",
        comment: "none"
    }, {
        value: "TestScript",
        type: "type 2",
        comment: "lots"
    }, {
        value: "AlphaScript",
        type: "type 3",
        comment: "even more"
    }, {
        value: "BravoScript",
        type: "type 4",
        comment: "lots and lots"
    }, {
        value: "CharlieScript",
        type: "type 5",
        comment: "comment"
    }, {
        value: "DeltaScript",
        type: "type 6",
        comment: "no comment"
    }],
    minLength: 1,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var header = "<li style='border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-top: 10px;'>" +
            "<a style='font-size:1em;font-weight:bold; display:inline-block;'>" +
            "<span class='ui-span'>Product</span><span class='ui-span'>Type</span>" +
            "<span class='ui-span'>Comment</span></a></li>"

        $("ul.ui-autocomplete[style*='block']").find("li:first").before(header);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log($(this.element))
        newLine()
    }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
        .append("<a><span class='ui-span'>" + item.value +
        "</span><span class='ui-span'>" + item.type +
        "</span><span class='ui-span' style='width:250px;'>" + item.comment + "</span></a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on your problem a bit, i've seen this line:

```
var row = $("#test tr:last").clone(true);
```

And this line is the problem, more specifically the "true" bool parametter.
As you can see on [jquery .clone docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents):

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements...

This basically means that everything on that element will be clonned, handdlers, triggers, etc... Every time you use your first input element, you will be able to see the autocomplete working and cloning lines.

So, change this:

```
var row = $("#test tr:last").clone(true);
```

To this:

```
var row = $("#test tr:last").clone();
```

I've made a more "clean" version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JuanHB/8uhNq/3/